# How can I insert a character in this array

Tags: php

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
  echo "$key=".urldecode($value)."<br/>";
}
```

the result is:

```
id=http://google.com/?var=234
k=234
ks=333
```

How can I insert the "&" in this array so it would output like this.

```
$param = "id=http://google.com/?var=234&k=234&ks=333";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http-build-query)

```
echo http_build_query($_GET);
```

Comment: But how?My code is this.<?php
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
  echo "$key=".urldecode($value)."<br/";
  }
 where can I put this?$param = http_build_query();

?>

Comment: did you want to add a $ 
@khem it builds it from an array, its an inbuilt php function that does the heavy lifting for you, checkout the link KingCrunch gave

Comment: @Bruce: Oneliner and a typo ... Thanks ;) @khem: Just read the manual (and have a look at the examples provided there). This function replaces your whole `foreach`-loop. There is no reason to reinvent the wheel.